# Flip multiple strings vertically on bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, paste, fold

I am trying to flip the contents of any sentence vertically. So each chars of any string will get printed vertically in same line.  For Example:

```
Sample Text: This is an Example

Output expected: T i a E
                 h s n x
                 i     a
                 s     m
                       p
                       l 
                       e
```

In following direction I am trying to achieve this but not able to yet.

```
    echo "Input provided by user is $@"
    for i in $(seq 1 $#); do

        echo ${!i} | sed 's/./ &/g' | xargs |tr ' ' '\n' 

        done


Current output:

T
h
i
s
i
s
a
n
E
x
a
m
p
l
e
```

Also, This is also not helping

```
echo Print text vertically | fold -c -w1
T
h
i
s

i
s

a
n

E
x
a
m
p
l
e
```

More alternatives which did not worked :

```
#echo "Input provided by user is $@"

for i in $(seq 1 $#); do

content[i]=$(echo ${!i}|fold -c -w1)

   #echo ${content[i]}


    done

    echo ${content[@]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max` variable holds the max length among all words. For your text it would be: `length('Example')` which is 7 (maximum out of lengths of all words)

Using an `awk` script file:

```
$ awk -f script.awk <<< "This is an Example"
TiaE
hsnx
i  a
s  m
   p
   l
   e
```

And here is the script:

```
{
        max=0
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                max=length($i)>max?length($i):max;

        for(j=1;j<=max;j++)
        {
                for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                {
                        temp=substr($i, j, 1);
                        printf temp==""?" ":temp
                }
                printf "\n"
        }
}
```

Comment: Comparison operations, other than `~` and `!~`, are not valid within simple print statements (print statements without parenthesis) in standard `awk` grammer.  [See the standard under  `non_unary_print_expr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_16)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
function abc(){
maxIteration=0;
for i in $(seq 1 $#); do
j=$(echo ${!i})
if [ $maxIteration -lt ${#j} ]
then
maxIteration=${#j};
fi
done
COUNTER=0;
while [ $COUNTER -lt $maxIteration ]; do
             for i in $(seq 1 $#); do
                j=$(echo ${!i})
                if [ ${#j} -gt $COUNTER ]
                then
                        echo ${j:$COUNTER:1} | tr '\n' ' ';
                else
                        echo " " | tr '\n' ' ';
                fi
             done
echo -e "\n"

                let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
         done
}

abc $@| grep .
```

Answer (score 1):

I had created some similar script before. A short but complete POC:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
max=0
#first determine the longest string so we can later pad shorter strings with spaces
for i in $(echo "$1" | xargs -d: -i  echo {})
do
    size=$(echo $i | wc -c)
    if [[ $size > $max ]]
    then
    max=$size
    fi 
done

files=""
#then echo the strings vertically inside the tmp files
for i in $(echo "$1" | xargs -d: -i  echo {})
do
    res=$(echo $i | sed 's/./ &/g'  | xargs |tr ' ' '\n' > /tmp/$count.out)
    #and add spaces at the end
    add_space=$((max-$(echo $i | wc -c)))
    for space in $(seq 0 $add_space)
    do                   
    echo " " >> /tmp/$count.out
    done
    files=$files" $count.out"
    count=$((count+1))
done
#and finally print them side by side
pr -t -J -m -w 70 -S" " $files
```

I create tmp files under /tmp, echo the string vertical and later use `pr` to print it out.

```
% ./s.sh "This is an Example"
T i a E
h s n x
i     a
s     m
      p
      l
      e
```

Comment: Use a secure facility for temporary files.  While being able to hack your script may seem unimportant, it can be used as an attack vector against system binaries. See e.g. the `mktemp` command on Debian; its manual page points out some flaws in earlier implementations.

Comment: Thanks for that comment!! I'll make sure my new scripts use 'mktemp'.

Answer (score 1):

Because Perl is fun:

```
perl -a script.pl <<< 'This is an Example'
T i a E 
h s n x 
i     a 
s     m 
      p 
      l 
      e
```

And the script:

```
@F = map { [/./g] } @F;
while (grep @{$_}, @F) {
  printf "%s ", shift @{$_} || ' ' for @F;
  print "\n"
}
```

Alternative script:

```
perl -pe '$r.=$/while/\S/&&s/(\S)(\S*)|\B/$r.=($1||$").$";$2/ge}{$_=$r' \
  <<< 'This is an Example'
T i a E   
h s n x   
i     a   
s     m   
      p   
      l   
      e
```